# Bootstrap 4 CSS not respect columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I currently have the following HTML. For brevity's sake, I'm only putting the divs and part of the inner content which is an input field, label and image.  This div is repeated 2 times with some change to the data.

```html
<div class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="option col-6 radioLabelContainer">
        <input />
        <label> </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2" style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
        <img style="height: 45px;" src="{{ asset("storage/".$turnaroundTime[0]->image_path) }}" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <button>Get New Price</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above produces this:

[image: Preview]

I attempt to remove the last div and change the code to this:

```html
<div class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="option col-6 radioLabelContainer">
        <input />
        <label> </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6" style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
        <img style="height: 45px;" src="{{ asset("storage/".$turnaroundTime[0]->image_path) }}" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

My assumption is that the `col-6` and `col-6` would be respected and it would put each side by side with the next div in another row.  However this is not the case.  It breaks and it does this (see below):

[image: Preview]

What am I doing wrong? The desired result would be that I would have two 6 columns side by side with the next row also containing the two 6 columns.

CSS for `radioLabelContainer`:

```css
.radioLabelContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
    align-items: center; /* align vertical */
    position: relative;
    grid-template-columns: 20px auto 100px;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 65px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    background-color: transparent;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in;
}
```

Comment: Seems like there is a conflict between the col-6 CSS from Bootstrap and your flex CSS in .radioLabelContainer. You also mix in grid-template-columns and grid-gap that may conflict with the flex properties. Hard to tell what's happening without running the code in an editor (use the built-in editor or Codepen or similar).

Comment: VERSION 4 @j08691